# Can VoiceXML automate the dialing for a employee for me

Tags: c#, tapi, voicexml, ccxml

My company has to test our client's telephone numbers to make sure they are working and that an operater is on the other line answering customers' calls. Right now the employee looks at a list of phone#'s from an excel sheet and manually dials on a touchphone, confirms if the number works or not and move on.

I would like to integrate this into our proprietary software to make the calls for the employee. Can VoiceXML dial a number and simply transfer the call to employee so that the employee can talk to the operator through a headset on the computer?

We run a C# platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VoiceXML, itself, has no ability to generate calls.  It's primary purpose is to direct the interaction between the caller and the IVR.  The VoiceXML standard includes blind transfer and bridging transfers.  Most platforms often provide additional extensions associated with call transfers.

Call generation is usually performed as a platform specific feature or via [CCXML's Createcall](http://www.w3.org/TR/ccxml/#Createcall) element.  CCXML also has transfer and other call manipulation features.

To solve your problem, you need to look into your platform documents and find how/if it supports outbound dialing.  Depending on how TAPI is implemented on your platform, you may find that a better control mechanism.